# How do I play Cthulhu Saves the World in windowed mode?

Tags: cthulhu-saves-the-world

Just wondering how to play said game in windowed mode.

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

From the main menu, select "Options & Credits" > "Screen"

From there you can choose between Fullscreen, 720p and SD windows. :)